# What does COUNT(DISTINCT x || y) mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you please help me to understand what this expression means in Oracle SQL?

```
COUNT(DISTINCT x || y)
```

is it just concatenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is just concatenation. It's a simple way to emulate counting the distinct tuples `(x, y)`, which is not possible with `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` in Oracle.

Depending on the data set, it has a flaw, because it returns the wrong result on the following data set

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT x || y)
FROM (
  SELECT 'a' x, 'bc' y FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ab' x, 'c' y FROM dual
) t
```

Comment: I don't know about Oracle, but in SQL Server (which is what I work with normally), when you concatenate two strings and one of them is null, the result of the concatenation is also null. This might be another problem in this method.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: In Oracle, concatenating `NULL` is the same thing as concatenating `''` (which again is the same thing as `NULL`)

Comment: Thanks for the info (though I saying that an empty string is the same as null seems strange [Is that an Oracle thing?])

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Yes this is an Oracle thing. And while I once had my reservations about this, I've come to love it. In all my SQL years I haven't seen a single case where a differentiation between empty strings and null strings would have been beneficial. After all, this `'' is null` thing is even less error-prone than the standard behavior.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: In some cases you're right. But in others, (e.g. `x = ''` doesn't work, nor does `x NOT IN ('a', 'b', '')`) it's a problem. Empty strings are a thing, and they are not the same thing as SQL's notorious `NULL`. In fact, I'd even go as far as saying that Oracle's behaviour is useful almost *only* with concatenation, where indeed the standard behviour is less useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the concatanation and as correctly said by @Lukas, this will not give the correct result.

To get the correct result, You can put some delimiter between two columns but make sure that that delimiter is not used in any columns.

`````
COUNT(DISTINCT x || '````' || y)  -- I am using four times ` as delimeter
`````